# Does TBB scalable allocator emphasize memory fragmentation?

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks, multicore, tbb

I have a video retrieval system which cosumes a lot of memory during retrieval process. I know tbb scalable allocator releases the freed memory to a memory pool and does not return it to the OS. Does this mean the pool will have those previous allocated memory in its pool all the time and when other threads need memory it may cause a memory exhaust?

I am using 2 machine of 24 cores,47G memory. My programme has 24 thread and each thread handle one retrieval task and use tbb scalable allocator for memory allocation but it still get bad alloc exception. I also used valgrind to detect memory leaks and find the report below which seems it only has "still reachable" problems caused by tbb scalable allocator and no other memory leaks. Can anybody show me how to solve this problem?

```
==1224== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1224==     in use at exit: 147,456 bytes in 9 blocks
==1224==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 1 frees, 148,480 bytes allocated
==1224== 
==1224== Thread 1:
==1224== 16,384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==1224==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==1224==    by 0x4E285C6: rml::internal::getRawMemory(unsigned long, bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AB2B: rml::internal::BackRefMaster::findFreeBlock() (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AE49: rml::internal::BackRefIdx::newBackRef(bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E26C49: rml::internal::MemoryPool::getEmptyBlock(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27676: rml::internal::internalPoolMalloc(rml::MemoryPool*, unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27825: scalable_malloc (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4C21278: operator new(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x458922: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<__gnu_cxx::_Hashtable_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:88)
==1224==    by 0x458947: __gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*>, unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::_M_get_node() (hashtable.h:297)
==1224==    by 0x458963: __gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*>, unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::_M_new_node(std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> const&) (hashtable.h:605)
==1224==    by 0x458ABC: __gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*>, unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::insert_equal_noresize(std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> const&) (hashtable.h:783)
==1224== 
==1224== 16,384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==1224==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==1224==    by 0x4E285C6: rml::internal::getRawMemory(unsigned long, bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AB2B: rml::internal::BackRefMaster::findFreeBlock() (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AE49: rml::internal::BackRefIdx::newBackRef(bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2A690: rml::internal::mallocLargeObject(rml::internal::ExtMemoryPool*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27825: scalable_malloc (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4C21278: operator new(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4553AC: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<s_Keypoint*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:88)
==1224==    by 0x4553D4: std::_Vector_base<s_Keypoint*, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:127)
==1224==    by 0x455C33: std::vector<s_Keypoint*, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<s_Keypoint**, std::vector<s_Keypoint*, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> > >, s_Keypoint* const&) (vector.tcc:275)
==1224==    by 0x455E87: std::vector<s_Keypoint*, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::push_back(s_Keypoint* const&) (stl_vector.h:610)
==1224==    by 0x45711C: DirectHash::getNeighbors1(std::vector<s_Keypoint*, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >&, unsigned int) (directhash.cpp:157)
==1224== 
==1224== 49,152 bytes in 3 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==1224==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==1224==    by 0x4E285C6: rml::internal::getRawMemory(unsigned long, bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AB2B: rml::internal::BackRefMaster::findFreeBlock() (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AE49: rml::internal::BackRefIdx::newBackRef(bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E26C49: rml::internal::MemoryPool::getEmptyBlock(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27676: rml::internal::internalPoolMalloc(rml::MemoryPool*, unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27825: scalable_malloc (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4C21278: operator new(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x458922: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<__gnu_cxx::_Hashtable_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:88)
==1224==    by 0x458947: __gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*>, unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::_M_get_node() (hashtable.h:297)
==1224==    by 0x458963: __gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*>, unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::_M_new_node(std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> const&) (hashtable.h:605)
==1224==    by 0x458A42: __gnu_cxx::hashtable<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*>, unsigned int, __gnu_cxx::hash<unsigned int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> >, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<s_Keypoint*> >::insert_equal_noresize(std::pair<unsigned int const, s_Keypoint*> const&) (hashtable.h:776)
==1224== 
==1224== 65,536 bytes in 4 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==1224==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==1224==    by 0x4E285C6: rml::internal::getRawMemory(unsigned long, bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AB2B: rml::internal::BackRefMaster::findFreeBlock() (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E2AE49: rml::internal::BackRefIdx::newBackRef(bool) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E26C49: rml::internal::MemoryPool::getEmptyBlock(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27676: rml::internal::internalPoolMalloc(rml::MemoryPool*, unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4E27825: scalable_malloc (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x4C21278: operator new(unsigned long) (in /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/build/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
==1224==    by 0x453A97: readKeysFromFile(char const*, int) (keypoint.cpp:329)
==1224==    by 0x45D929: KeypointDB::Add(char const*) (keypointdb.cpp:201)
==1224==    by 0x44A264: MRSystem::MRServer::AddFingerPrint(std::string) (mrserver.cpp:68)
==1224==    by 0x445D68: MRSystem::Slave::ConstructHashTable() (Slave.cpp:242)
==1224== 
==1224== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1224==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1224==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1224==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1224==    still reachable: 147,456 bytes in 9 blocks
==1224==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1224== 
==1224== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1224== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1224== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

In versions prior to 4.0, memory blocks used by tbbmalloc to allocate "small" (<8K) objects were only available for reuse by the thread that requested it from OS. So the situation described in the question - "a thread will have those previous allocated memory in its pool all the time and when other threads need memory it may cause a memory exhaust" - was possible.

Since v4.0 (released in 2011), the TBB memory allocator may return all memory back to the OS. So the described problem is not relevant anymore. If someone still uses an older version of tbbmalloc and experiences the described problem, the solution is to upgrade the allocator.